# why floor gives the wrong value?

Tags: c++, math, floor

Upon dividing 2.4/0.8 we will get output as 3.00
Upon applying floor am getting the output as 2.00
But my expectation is floor(2.4/0.8) == floor(3.00).
But the result  of floor(2.4/0.8) gives 2 instead of 3.

I can't visualize what is going wrong here.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <cmath>


int main()
{
   double d=2.4/0.8;

   printf("\n  :: %lf ",d);
   printf("\n  :: %lf ",floor(d)  );

   return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
 :: 3.000000
 :: 2.000000
```

Comment: Your value may be something like 2.999, and at the precision you requested this is printed as "3.00".

Comment: Try looking at the value in a debugger or printing with more digits.

Comment: [Floating point is inexact](http://floating-point-gui.de/). See the [actual value](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d2cb3037ca4ebb02).

Comment: @crashmstr: I blame it on poor software systems education!